# HTTP request using fopen and curl_setopt

Tags: php, http, curl, fopen

If cURL is unavailable I want to send HTTP requests using fopen.  I got the code for a class from a PACKT RESTful PHP book but it does nto work.  Any ideas why?

```
if ($this->with_curl) {     
  //blah
} else {    
    $opts = array (
            'http' => array (
            'method' => "GET",
            'header'  => array($auth,
            "User-Agent: " . RESTClient :: USER_AGENT . "\r\n"),
            )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
    $result = fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Could you be any more specific as to why "it doesn't work"?

Comment: .... And post the contents of auth.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, you're using `fpassthru()`. If you want `$result` to contain the actual response, you cannot use that function as it spills the result into the output buffer and doesn't return it.

Comment: auth is  "username:password". I have tried removing this but still don't get anything.  I have also remoeved fpassthru() as suggested and still nothing.  By "it doesn't work", I mean nothing is being outputted when I echo out $result.  I get a blank page...thanks for you help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTTP context options are laid out here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

The `header` option is a string, so as @Mob says you should be using `\r\n` and string concatenation rather than an array. However, `user_agent` is a valid key, so you could just use that instead.

I'm guessing that the contents of the `$auth` variable is something along the lines of `Authorization: blah` - i.e. standard header format?

The below code is a working example. Note that I've changed your `fpassthru()` (which outputs the content to the browser, and does not store it to `$result`) to a `fread()` loop. Alternatively you could have wrapped the `fpassthru()` call with `ob_start();` and `$result = ob_get_clean();`

```
<?php
class RESTClient {
  const USER_AGENT = 'bob';
}
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$username = "fish";
$password = "paste";
$b64 = base64_encode("$username:$password");
$auth = "Authorization: Basic $b64";
$opts = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => $auth,
            'user_agent' => RESTClient :: USER_AGENT,
        )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
$result = "";
while ($str = fread($fp,1024)) {
    $result .= $str;
}
fclose($fp);
echo $result;
```

Comment: ok, Ive tried using your working example and still not getting any results.  I need to use HTTP basic authorisation and asume this is what I am doing wrong.  But if this is wrong surley I should get some error?

Comment: What is the contents of your `$auth` var?

Comment: Ive tried passing $auth as "username:password" and also tried "Authentication:username:password". I cannot find any documentation on how this should be done.

Comment: Base64 encode `username:password` and then stick it into the header - see updated answer `Authorization: Basic base64(username:password)`

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing this. Shouldn't it be ::

```
$opts = array (
            'http' => array (
            'method' => "GET",
            'header'  => $auth . "\r\n" . //removed array()
                        "User-Agent: " . RESTClient :: USER_AGENT . "\r\n" )
            )
```

Here's an example of setting headers from the PHP manual

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);
```